# How to sort ascending number of array at Javascrtipt only using for-loop, if statement and while-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, while-loop

I wanna ascend this array below.
[1, 2,3,5, 3, 2, 4,] to [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]

but my code below didn't back correctly answer.
Could someone teach me how to sort array of numbers using javascript?

```
    var arr = [1, 2,3,5, 3, 2, 4,];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
    var left = arr[i];
    var right = arr[i + 1];
    if (left > right) {
        arr[i + 1] = left;
        arr[i] = right;
    } 

}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: looks like a single iteration of bubblesort (incorrect one)

Comment: you can use this [`[1, 2,3,5, 3, 2, 4].sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

Here is bubble sort algorithm using only `for-loop` and `while`

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4];

let is_sorted = false;

while (!is_sorted) {
  is_sorted = true;
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) {
      // swap
      const temp = arr[i - 1];
      arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp;
      is_sorted = false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer! I don't have any ideas to use while-loop! Thanks!!